# YouTube increase volume via js?

Tags: javascript, html, youtube

I want to increase the volume of a youtube video (directly on youtube.com, not an iframe) with some js. I have tried:

```
function volumeup() { let evt = new KeyboardEvent('keydown', { shiftKey: false, key: 'ArrowUp', keyCode: 38 }); document.dispatchEvent(evt); }
```

But it doesn't seem to work. And since the youtube volume slider is not a 'real' slider, ...

```
<div class="ytp-volume-slider" style="touch-action: none;">
<div class="ytp-volume-slider-handle" style="left: 21.55px;">
</div></div>
```

... I have no clue how to control it else.

Kind regards.

Comment: Instead of trying to simulate an event you can just get a reference of the video an increase its volume.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
document.querySelector('.ytd-watch-flexy .html5-main-video').volume += 0.1
```

Note! this selector can be changed, so it can be a good idea loop over all video elements in page.

Comment: Hey, thank you for your answer. But sadly I don't see or hear any changes. *But* in the console is a number (0-1) that gets higher. Also setting it directly didn't change anything : /

Comment: With directly I mean removing the + and just set it to a specific value...

Comment: If you use the snippet above but instead set the volume to 0 it doesn't mute the video?

Comment: hi,
This was an example of guidance. The volume can range from 0 to 1. Therefore, when the value is 1, adding 0.1 to it will have no effect.
You can set the volume to a certain value using "=" operator or increase using "+=" or decrease using "-=". If you use the increase or decrease operator, you should really add a mechanism to check that the value does not exceed 1 or less than 0.
To mute, the correct way is not to set the volume to 0, but to set the "muted" property